# Converting from bitstring to integer

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I need a function like

`int GetIntegerFromBinaryString(string binary, int bitCount)`

if binary = "01111111" and bitCount = 8, it should return 127

if binary = "10000000" and bitCount = 8, it should return -128

The numbers are stored in 2's complement form. How can I do it. Is there any built in functions that would help so that I needn't calculate manually.

Comment: Are there any boundaries to the bitCount? For example can it be assumed that bitCount will always be <=32?

Comment: should it return -256 on "100000000" and bitCount = 9 ?

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @deepee bitcount will be <= 32 in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go.

```
    static int GetIntegerFromBinaryString(string binary, int bitCount)
    {
        if (binary.Length == bitCount && binary[0] == '1')
            return Convert.ToInt32(binary.PadLeft(32, '1'),2);
        else
            return Convert.ToInt32(binary,2);
    }
```

Convert it to the 2-s complement version of a 32 bit number, then simply let the Convert.ToInt32 method do it's magic.

Comment: @ajay haha yes, didn't notice there were answers popping in and out. +1 to you as well ;p

Answer (score 5):

Prepend the string with 0's or 1's to make up to the bitCount and do
`int number = Convert.ToInt16("11111111"+"10000000", 2);`